# Limiting distribution of sum of normals

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

How would I go about solving this problem below? I am not exactly sure where to start. I know that I need to make use of the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem as well. Thanks for the help.

> Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be a random sample of size $n$ from a distribution that is $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ where $\sigma^2 > 0$. Show that $Z_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$ does not have a limiting distribution.

Comment: I like this problem.  Many people who have taken only a basic course in probability retain the impression that the Central Limit Theorem says that "if you add up a bunch of random numbers, you get a normal distribution (in the limit)."  Finite variance or the need for scaling etc are long forgotten.  This problem points out that even the sum of iid normal random variables does not  approach a normal distribution, let alone the sum of a "bunch of random numbers."

Comment: Do you know about characteristic functions?

Comment: I know about mgfs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not see Lebesgue dominated convergence in here.

Rather, you could try to compute the distribution of $Z_n$ for each $n$ (hint: this is gaussian) and then show that $\mathrm P(|Z_n|\leqslant z)\to0$ for every fixed $z$ (hint: write each $Z_n$ as $a_nY_n+b_n$ with $Y_n$ standard gaussian and try to include each event $[|Z_n|\leqslant z]$ in an event $[|Y_n|\leqslant y_n]$ with $y_n\to0$).

If one of these steps causes you some trouble and once you will have shown what you tried, please ask for further indications.

**Edit** After some exchanges in the comments, we know that $Z_n=\sqrt{n}\sigma Y_n+n\mu$ hence $|Z_n|\leqslant z$ if and only if $|Y_n+\sqrt{n}\mu/\sigma|\leqslant z/(\sqrt{n}\sigma)$. For the condition that $|Z_n|\leqslant z$ to hold, $Y_n$ must belong to the interval centered at $-\sqrt{n}\mu/\sigma$ of length $2z/(\sqrt{n}\sigma)$. Since the density of $Y_n$ is uniformly bounded by $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$, this shows that
$$
\mathrm P(|Z_n|\leqslant z)\leqslant2z/(\sqrt{2\pi n}\sigma)\to0.
$$
Alternatively, one could have noted from the start that the density of $Z_n$ is uniformly bounded by $1/(\sqrt{2\pi n}\sigma)$ and that one asks $Z_n$ to be in an interval of length $2z$.

In any case, if $Z_n\to \zeta$ in distribution and if $\zeta$ is not almost surely infinite, there exists $z$ such that $\mathrm P(|\zeta|\leqslant z)\geqslant\frac12$, say, hence $\mathrm P(|Z_n|\leqslant z)$ cannot converge to zero. This shows $Z_n$ cannot converge in distribution to a random variable $\zeta$ such that $\mathrm P(|\zeta|=\infty)\ne1$.

**Note** As this proof shows, my first indication (which was to include $[|Z_n|\leqslant z]$ in $[|Y_n|\leqslant y_n]$ with $y_n\to0$) was wrong since the suitable event involving $Y_n$ is **NOT** of the form $[|Y_n|\leqslant y_n]$ with $y_n\to0$ but $[|Y_n+t_n|\leqslant y_n]$ with $y_n\to0$ and $|t_n|\to\infty$. I leave everything as it was first written.

Comment: Does this require the use of Slutsky's theorem?

Comment: No. First, each $X_n$ is distributed like a standard gaussian $X$ hence $P(|X_n|\leqslant x_n)=P(|X|\leqslant x_n)$ for every $n$. Second, the distribution of $X$ has no atom at $0$ hence, if $x_n\to0$, $P(|X|\leqslant x_n)\to0$. Hence all this reduces to show that $x_n\to0$. The first step is to compute $a_n$ and $b_n$.

Comment: Would Z be a multivariate normal? I can't say it is normal with a mean of n * mew and a variance of n * sigma ^2 because they are not independent. Correct? The reason I need to find Z and a linear combination of A and B is so that I can find its distribution using the theorems associated with the multivariate normal. Is that also correct?

Comment: *Multivariate* refers to random variables with values in $\mathbb R^n$ with $n>1$. Your $Z$ lives in $\mathbb R$, so no. // *Random sample* usually means independent random variables $X_i$. If the $X_i$ are not independent, the distribution of $Z$ can be **VERY** complicated hence their independence is a hypothesis you are supposed to make, I think.

Comment: Could you please give me further guidance on how to write Zn as a linear combination of a and b? Am I correct in thinking that Xn is a normal with mean n*mew and variance of n * sigma^2?

Comment: Just realized I used $X_n$ in my answer, forgetting that you used this notation for something else in the question, so my hint might have been difficult to decipher. Sorry about that. Try the new version. Anyway, yes $Z_n$ is normal with mean $n\mu$ and variance $n\sigma^2$ and you want $Z_n=a_nY_n+b_n$ with $Y_n$ normal with mean $0$ and variance $1$. So $a_n=\ldots$ and $b_n=\ldots$

Comment: Well since all parameters of Z are being multiplied by n, I would guess that a = n and b = 0. If that is correct, then do I need to express Z as an event that involves Y? Then do I need to find the limiting distribution of that? And I assume that there will be no limiting distribution given what the question has asked...

Comment: $a_n=n$ and $b_n=0$ are both incorrect, since, if $Y_n$ is normal with mean $0$ and variance $1$, then $nY_n+0$ is normal with mean $0$ and variance $n^2$. You want $a_nY_n+b_n$ to be normal with mean $n\mu$ and variance $n\sigma^2$. As I said in my answer, this is the first step. The second step is to include $[|Z_n|\leqslant z]$ into $[|Y_n|\leqslant y_n]$ for a suitable $y_n$. And the third and final step is to show that $y_n\to0$ and to draw some consequences. But, **first things first**: what are $a_n=\ldots$ and $b_n=\ldots$?

Comment: Makes sense now! I guess a = root n * sigma and b = n * mew. I have no clue how to approach the second part though... Thanks for all the help.

Comment: See edit. Sorry for the mistake in my previous indication, one must replace the interval $[-y_n,y_n]$ by a non centered interval (and then everything works fine).

Comment: @Did why are you working with $\mathrm P(|Z_n|\leqslant z)$ and not $\mathrm P(Z_n\leqslant z)$

Comment: @Did why does $\mathrm P(|Z_n|\leqslant z)\to0 \Rightarrow \mathrm P(Z_n\leqslant z)\to0$

Comment: @n.e. The implication you imagined is not in my answer and not true.

Comment: @Did I guess my question is why does showing that the distribution of $|Z_n|$ converging to 0, which means $|Z_n|$ has no limiting distribution, imply that $Z_n$ has no limiting distribution?

Comment: @n.e. Because if $Z_n$ converges in distribution then $u(Z_n)$ converges in distribution, say, for every continuous function $u$, in particular, $|Z_n|$ converges in distribution

Comment: @Did im sorry if im missing something but I dont see what conclusion we can make about the limiting distribution of $Z_n$ from showing $|Z_n|$ has no limiting distribution. Could you try to explain it please

Comment: @n.e. Sorry but I just did explain exactly this: *if $|Z_n|$ does not converge in distribution then $Z_n$ does not converge in distribution*. If this statement is not clear to you, this might mean that you need to repolish your knowledge of the notion of convergence in distribution, and you might want to post the queries you have about it as a new question.

Comment: @Did you wrote in the last comment that $|Z_n|$ does converge in distribution, thats what confused me.

Comment: @n.e. Ah. So things are even simpler: you need to revise the logical meaning of **if... then...** sentences.

Comment: @Did I understand the if then statement. $Z_n$ converges in dist then $u(Z_n)$ converges in dist for any continuous $u$ or if there exists a continuous $u$ such that $u(Z_n)$ does not converge in dist then $Z_n$ does not converge in dist.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to show $P(Z_n\le z)=0$ for all $z$ as Did suggests:

Note that $Z_n\sim N(n\mu, n\sigma^2)$, so for some fixed real number $z$, $P(Z_n\le z)=\frac{1}{2}\biggr[1+erf\biggr(\frac{z-n\mu}{\sqrt{2n\sigma^2}}\biggr)\biggr]\to0$ as $n\to\infty$,

since $\frac{z-n\mu}{\sqrt{2n\sigma^2}}\to-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}erf(x)=-1$.

Hence the limit of the CDFs is equal to 0 everywhere, and cannot limit to a CDF.

[I use the definition of erf from the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution]